# How do I deal with this broadcasting/indexing issue in numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

I've been trying to figure something out in numpy and I'm hoping somebody with some experience with the package can help me out. I have a two-dimensional array of prices, and an accompanying array that tells me whether I should use these prices or not:

```
prices = np.random.rand(12,4)
use_prices = np.array([[False, False, False, True, True, False, True, True,  True,  False, False, False],
                       [False, False, True,  True, True, True,  False, True, False, False, False, False]])
```

I also have a 3-d array of holdings, for which these prices apply. These represent the holdings that apply for every one of the prices that are valid (ie, those that are True in use_prices):

```
holdings = np.array([[[1,0,1,0]],[[0,1,0,1]]])
holdings
array([[[1, 0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 0, 1]]])
```

and finally I have an empty array of values, which are ultimately going to consist of the prices multiplied by the holdings. This is a 3-d array because there are two sets of holdings, and then the 12x4 array of prices.

```
values_array = np.full((2,12,4), np.nan)
```

What I would like to do is to fill the values array with the holdings * prices for the two sets of holdings, for the valid prices. In numpy pseudocode I imagine this would go something like this:

```
values_array[use_prices_bool] = (prices * holdings)[use_prices_bool]
```

Can anyone tell me if there is a good way to do this, and if so what it is? Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have 48 different prices and 24 different use_price bools. Does each use_price bool apply to 2 prices? If so, it is unclear from the description how `use_prices` should affect price selection.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko - thanks for the response - I am trying to create two ultimate sets of values (hence dim0 = 2 in the final values_array). So the each element of dim1 of use_prices applies to an entire row of prices, and each element of dim0 connects to the two ultimate sets of values. Apologies if the example is a bit confusing.

Comment: I am still a bit confused, but maybe something like this will work: `values_array[use_prices, :] = (prices * holdings)[use_prices, :]`. Your pseudocode seems right except that you need the number of dimensions in the index to line up with the number of dimensions in an array.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko - thanks, I think it is something like that. I am gradually blundering towards a correct answer and I'll put it up if I ever get to it.